# Why does skipping occurs when using std::remove() to remove more than one value from a vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector

I am doing a [challenge](https://github.com/YearOfProgramming/2017Challenges/blob/master/challenge_2/README.md/) that I stumbled upon Reddit the other night where you do one programming challenge a day. It seems really nice, and provides a lot of practice for myself as I learn.

I have hit this one problem where I try to remove something from a vector using `std::remove()` and it removes the desired numbers, and here is the issue, the next number after it. I have tried doing other functions and various ways of doing this, but this seems the most practical, and feels so close to what I need.

#### My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>  // std::sort(), std::remove()
#include <vector>


void print_array(std::vector<int> array)
{
  std::cout << "Array: ";
  for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
  {
    std::cout << array.at(i) << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> num_array = {2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 4, 6, 9, 10, 9, 8, 7, 8, 10, 7};

  // Sort ant then print the array.
  std::sort(num_array.begin(), num_array.end());
  print_array(num_array);

  for(int i = 0; i < num_array.size(); i++)
  {
    if(num_array.at(i) == num_array.at(i + 1))
    {
      std::cout << num_array.at(i) << " is duped\n";
      num_array.erase(std::remove(num_array.begin(), num_array.end(), num_array.at(i)), num_array.end());
      print_array(num_array);
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << num_array.at(i) << " is not duped.\n";
    }
  }


  print_array(num_array);
  return 0;
}
```

#### Output

[image: output image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove` takes the thing to be removed by const reference, and operates on the assumption that it doesn't change throughout the removal process.

Your code violates that assumption. For instance, in the first iteration, you pass `num_array[0]` by reference to `remove`, but that element is soon overwritten by a later element (with the value `3`) and then all the subsequent comparisons get messed up because they end up using the new value.

Force a copy with unary `+`:

```
num_array.erase(std::remove(num_array.begin(), num_array.end(), +num_array[i]),
                num_array.end());
```

Then you'll see the problem pointed out in [Dietmar Kühl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41457441/2756719). Fix that too.

Comment: This ended up working! I have one question, what does using the unary + do exactly? Again - this is my first time working with vectors

Answer (score 2):

You increment your index even if you just removed the element. You only want to increment your index if you didn't remove an element.

Note, that your algorithm takes *O(N<sup>2</sup>)* time while it is possible to implement this functionality with *O(N)* complexity. Also, `std::vector<T>::at()` is an abomination which is best not used! In the best case it is just a waste of time, in the worst case it masks errors.

Comment: Assuming that the only bug is the incrementing, `std::unique` would take `[0,0,1,2]` and return `[0,1,2]`. Blake's code will return `[1,2]`.

Comment: @BillLynch: yes, I actually noticed that, too (I'm about to remove the comment about `std::unique()`). The incorrect increment remains, of course, as does the fact that there is an `O(N)` algorithm...

Comment: @DietmarKühl I am trying to completely remove anything that is duplicated. I should have said that, so say since there are three 4's, I need to remove them completely. The answer in the end should leave a 5 by itself.

Comment: @BlakeBarnes00: yes - as mentioned above to Bill Lynch, `std::unique()` doesn't quite do what you need to do. However, a `std::unique()`-like algorithm still yields an *O(N)* algorithm for the problem.

Comment: @DietmarKühl today was the first day I even used a Vector, I have a lot to learn clearly. And I am misunderstanding what you mean by those equations you keep repeating..

Comment: @BlakeBarnes00: you mean, you don't know what the [Big O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is? It is a measurement on how well an algorithm works by looking at how many operation it needs to do for large inputs. A *linear algorithm* (i.e., an algorithm in *O(N)*) is generally considered efficient (assuming it needs to touch all elements). A *quadratic algorithm* (i.e., an algorithm in _O(N*N)_) generally takes too long even on moderately sized inputs.

Comment: If there are N (say 10 million) random integers in the range 0-10, in the vector, your approach will take time proportional to N²,  (One factor of N to scan each element, another because removing an element requires shuffling down all the elements above it.)  A better algorithm scans forward from the beginning with *two* pointers/indices/iterators, one as destination and one as source.  If you find a duplicate, just advance source.  If you find a non-duplicate, move the value at source to the destination and advance both.  (Skip doing the move if source==dest).

Comment: OP's seeing broken behavior even before we get to the incrementing (or not) of `i`.

Comment: @T.C.: oh, right - `std::remove()` taking its argument by `const&`. I like your fix (adding a unary `+`). Once that problem is fixed, the issue of the incorrect increments still remain.